# Pi Zero W power through usb socket

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, power-management, usb-hub, pi-zero-w

Can I power a Pi Zero W and still use the usb hub at the sametime with this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use the USB Hub to power the Raspberry Pi Zero?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42220/can-i-use-the-usb-hub-to-power-the-raspberry-pi-zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer your question directly, as I don't have that particular OTG cable.
However, I do have a usb hub connected to my Pi Zero W USB data port, and the power from the hub is powering the Zero W as well as a few peripherals including a keyboard and a mouse with LED's onboard. No sweat.

You should be good to go.

Comment: Awesome thank you that's exactly what I need to know. It is able to power and send and receive data, I just didn't know if you could power a zero through the usb port as an alternative

Answer (score 2):

The Pi Zero W has two micro USB ports:

- Micro USB On-The-Go, labeled "USB" - this is where the hub is connected
- Micro USB power, labeled "PWR" - this is where the power supply for the Pi is connected

In other words: yes, you can do both things at the same time. This is exactly what both ports are for.

Addendum:

From the schematics of the [Pi Zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/RPI-ZERO-V1_3_reduced.pdf), and assuming that the Pi Zero W is similar in this respect, we find that the USB On-The-Go port's power line is connected to VBUS whereas the power port is connected to 5V. Unfortunately the schematics do not mention VBUS again at any other point.

However connecting the power supply to the data port does indeed power the Pi. This [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/38628/19949) supports that the Zero (again assuming the Zero W behaves the same way, which is likely) can be backpowered.

The final question now is whether the shown OTG hub powers the power line on its upstream port - which I cannot tell from the picture. If it is self powered (not bus powered) it is quite likely that it will work (with any drawbacks that may arise from backpowering). Make sure that the power supply's amperage covers the Pi and the connected peripherals.

Comment: I'm asking if I can power it through the usb socket and not the power socket

Comment: Well, that is not what your question reads.

Comment: Related: (assuming the Zero W is similar to the Zero in this) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/38642/19949

Comment: Actually it asks if I can power a pi zero with that device depicted above, I guess I should have specified that it would be plugged in the usb port

Comment: @kyranbullard is the hub self powered? If not where do you intend to connect to power supply?

Comment: There is a power intake on the far right of the pic micro usb and a switch on it to allow power to flow through

Answer (score 1):

I use a hub *exactly* like the one pictured with a Zero W. Works fine.

Comment: Welcome -- but this information perhaps isn't as useful as you think because you have not said *how* you are using it/what you are using it for.  Someone who misinterpreted the question could say exactly the same thing when (eg., if) it in fact won't work because what they were doing was something else... It would not hurt to add some clarification, in other words.